# Детеныш обезьяны

Tags: грамотная-речь

Тут уже были вопросы о названиях детенышей разных животных. Вчера была в зоопарке, пыталась рассказать о детеныше обезьян, но не знала, как их назвать. Обезьянчик? Обезьяныш?))))

Comment: Мои вчера спросили о детях крота... Сошлись на кротятах :))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По логике - "обезьянёнок". Также как львёнок оленёнок и так далее. Наличие данного термина подтверждает "Словарь синонимов", но как нетрудно догадаться слово не особо употребительное, лучше "детёныш" называть.

Comment: По логике — да. Но как-то оно неудобоваримо))))

Answer (score 2):

Если у вас не очень серьёзный (околонаучный) текст, то называйте как хотите.

Насколько понимаю, общние шло с достаточно маленькими детьми, поэтому "детёныш обезьяны" не прокатит. Не детская конструкция. Разве что просто "детёныш", "обезьяний детеныш" - если хотите какую-то "взрослость" придать разговору.
Обезьяненок - вполне сойдет. Детям понятно, они грамматику слова чувствуют получше взрослых.
Зато обезьяныш - это просто великолепно стилистически, дети тем более должны понять. Можно украсть?

Comment: Нет, я маме рассказывала. У нас потрясающий зоопарк в Ялте — там есть, о чем рассказывать.  
А украсть — запросто.)))

Answer (score 0):

> Вчера была в зоопарке, пыталась рассказать о детеныше обезьян, но не знала, как их назвать. Обезьянчик? Обезьяныш?))))

( Обезьяныш :-). Очень мило Вы, **writer**, сказали! )

Если **детям** в зоопарке объяснять, то могу предложить вариант *малыш обезьяны*.

А ещё дети отлично понимают такую взаимосвязь, как -- *это его мама, а то её ребёнок*. И при этом показываешь на взрослого зверя (птицу) и на маленького.
Или *папа и его ребёнок*.

А потом можно озвучить правильное название, если, конечно, его знаешь :-) . И чтобы человеческий ребёнок понял взаимосвязь слов. Лис - лисёнок, жираф - ... (да-а, много экзотических животных встречается в зоопарках).

Comment: ( Обезьяныш :-). Очень мило Вы, Надюшка, сказали! )   
  
Вообще-то, это я сказала))))

Comment: Ой, действительно! Прошу прощения.

Очень мило, ВЫ, **writer**, сказали! :-) 

Исправлю в тексте.

Comment: Тогда мой, ориентированный на ребёнка, ответ Вам, **writer**, пожалуй, не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Обезьянка. Другой вопрос, что это может означать любую обезьянку малого размера, даже взрослую особь